# Showing that $(5 \cos t, 5 \sin t, 10t)$ parameterizes an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, parametrization

> How can I understand this parametrization belongs to an ellipse?
>
> $$\vec{r}(t) = (5 \cos t, 5 \sin t, 10t); \; 0 < t < 2\pi$$

My attempt:

$$x(t) = 5 \cos t$$
$$y(t) = 5 \sin t$$
$$z(t) = 10t$$

I know the O-centered ellipse parametrization is

$$\vec{r}(t) = (a \cos t, b \sin t); \; t \in [0,2\pi]$$

While I'm not familiar yet with curves in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, what about the z-component? How can I plot this curve?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It parametrizes a helix. Notice that the projection on the $xy$-plane is a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an ellipse, it is a [**vertical helix**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Helix.html).

More in detail the projection onto x-y plane is a circle centered at the origin with radius $R=5$ indeed

$$x^2+y^2=(5\cos t)^2+(5\sin t)^2=25$$

Answer (score 0):

The ellipse will "seem" to be moving along the z axis. Imagine drawing an ellipse but at the same time, your pen moves normal to the paper.

If you want to plot it, try MATLAB (edit: or Wolfram Alpha is easier (type plot x=5cos(t), y=5sin(t), z=10t )).